# mongdb supports join queries?

Tags: mongodb

Can mongodb support the following SQL queries? I tried mongodb's $lookup, but $loopup only supports queries like a=b：

```
select c.cidr,sum(c.bps),sum(c.pps) from (select a.ip,a.pps,a.bps,b.cidr from iptables a join cachetables b on a.start>=b.start and a.end <=b.end)c group by c.cidr;
```

Here's my test data.

```
mysql> select * from iptables;
+-----------+-------+------+------+------+
| ip        | start | end  | pps  | bps  |
+-----------+-------+------+------+------+
| 168.1.1.1 |     1 |    2 |    1 |    1 |
| 168.1.1.2 |     3 |    4 |    2 |    2 |
| 168.1.1.6 |     5 |    6 |    6 |    6 |
| 168.2.2.1 |   101 |  102 |    6 |    6 |
| 168.2.2.2 |   103 |  104 |    6 |    6 |
| 168.2.2.2 |   103 |  104 |    6 |    6 |
+-----------+-------+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from cachetables;
+--------------+-------+------+
| cidr         | start | end  |
+--------------+-------+------+
| 168.1.1.0/24 |     1 |  100 |
| 168.2.2.0/24 |   101 |  200 |
+--------------+-------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: [$lookup examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#examples) supports "joins" between collections using various conditional operations - see the linked documentation _and_ the examples.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have read the documentation. The new version can support my needs. But unfortunately, our mongodb version is 3.2. It doesn't support flexible join queries yet.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/
According to the official documentation, flexible joins are supported from version 3.6, but my version is 3.2, so I'll have to find another workaround.

Comment: So, the answer to your question is 'No'?